# Titanium Alloy SplitWindow IOS strange behavior change width

Tags: javascript, ios7, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

```
  <SplitWindow id="home" platform="ios" formFactor="tablet">
            <Require src="master" id="master"/>
            <Require src="detail" id="detail"/>
  </SplitWindow>
```

I have a `strange behavior` if I drag horizontally the `black separation line` between the two windows.
The windows change size adapting to my movements.

[image]
[image]
[image]

And, if I change the `width` of the windows is even easier to identify the `black separation line`

```
function demo() {
Alloy.Globals.master.win.width = 512;
Alloy.Globals.detail.win.width = 512;
}
```

[image]
[image]

`[For test purpose you have to aim the exact pixel of the black separation line  ]`

Could you tell why is this happening and how do I stop this behavior??

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer what the "strange behavior" is? I'm guessing it's that the two lines are different widths. But I have to guess...

Comment: Have you tried setting `touchEnabled=false` on the `SplitWindow`?

Comment: The problem is that those 2 lines are not different "entities",
a second before the splitview works properly a second after it messes up everything and there is no way to set those sizes

Answer (score 0):

After I saw this problem posted, I tested my own SplitWindow application (which is not an Alloy application) and the bug exists there as well.

Everything I tried to prevent this from happening was useless. I believe it is to be considered a bug and should be reported at the Titanium JIRA.